# can not understand why i am gettting the error in this code?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
db.update();  
}  
});
```

> On line 1 ---> it is suggesting to convert setonclicklistener to setkeylistener
>   and on line 3 to remove override annotation but it should be there cant find error help me out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not mandatory to use `@Override` on `public void onClick(View v)`, but could be a good reason to verify that you aren't violating its signature. However, if you choose to use `@Override`, make sure your project is compliant with Java 1.6. If not, you might get the "... must override a superclass method" error. To enable this, right-click on your project folder inside Eclipse, and select `Properties` at the bottom. Then go to `Java Compiler` and select `1.6` from the dropdown menu at the top (`Compiler compliance level`).

Also make sure you are using `View`s `OnClickListener`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {
         db.update();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with overriding the method. In fact, I would recommend it, so it gives an error when you've accidentally used some wrong parameters.

Comment: OK, thanks. Added a clarification and a tip on how to avoid potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
db.update();  
}  
});
```

and make sure you are importing `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` package

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add View in front of OnClickListener like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
  @Override  
  public void onClick(View v) {  
    db.update();  
  }  
});
```

Another potential issue: the code inside OnClick will be run in the UI thread, updating the DB can be a long and blocking operation so you should not do that in the UI thread. Instead create a new thread.